# Joining 2 Objects Doesn't Make Them 1 Mesh

Tags: modeling, sculpting

I'm having an issue where I join 2 objects with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> and when I'm actually sculpting the newly formed object it's like there is a line between main object and the joined object where I'm not able to sculpt.

[image]
[image]

Comment: as you say, joining 2 objects doesn't make one mesh, the meshes stay separate, you can either boolean instead of joining, or, if you have joined you can select one of the meshes in Edit mode, go in the header menu > Face > Intersect (Boolean)

Comment: I've already joined them with ctrl+j and started sculpting on it, can you suggest anything at this point? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: yes, as I said, use the second method, go in Edit mode, select one of the 2 meshes with L, then go in the header menu > Face > Intersect (Boolean)

Comment: An object can contain several disconnected meshes and still be a single object. Pressing Ctrl + J is not going to connect the geometry by some magical miracle. If you want to connect the vertices into a single mesh you have to do it manually. If the vertices are close enough or overlapping try using "merge by distance".